# Set the caption of a frame in a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to set the caption of a frame **dynamically** inside a continuous form.

So far I am doing the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.myFrame.Caption = Me.created_date 
End Sub
```

**This only sets the value of the first record for all Frames.** I want the frame to have the "creation_date" of each entry of my table.

What do I have to do to make the caption dynamic ? The Frame control does not have a "Data" binding like textfields, so I think that I have to set it programmatically.

Comment: You could add the frame (do you mean the `Option Group` frame?), remove the label from the frame and add a text box and format it to look like the label - now you can add a Control Source to the text box so it displays the creation date.

Comment: Yes I mean the Option Group Frame. Your solution seems more like a workaround - there must be a way to set the caption dynamically (at least I'd like to think that). Positioning a bound Textbox over the empty caption sounds "dirty" :)

Comment: Yep, a workaround but it works as @Andre said.  I guess you could do something with code and the `On Current` event but why bother figuring it all out, writing a bunch of code when a text box will do the job for you?

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Record Source of your form to whichever table/query you're using.

Add the Option Group frame to the form and delete the label.
Place a text box where the deleted label was and format as needed.

Give the text box a Control Source pointing to your date field and it should just work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having this problem again, with buttons this time. By any chance, do you have an idea for a workaround ? I have a button that changes a value in the current record, and then the button should be disabled. If I disable it in the code, it is disabled for all entries of the continuous form.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly.

Unbound controls like the frame caption by definition have the same value for all records in a continuous form.

The only way is to use a bound control (textbox) as workaround, as shown by Darren.